# Comparing an element to last element in a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am working with 3 tables in PostgreSQL

```
1. documents: dId, title, subtitle
2. documentfolder: dfId, dId, type
3. staff: sId, dfId, sType
```

The relations between the table are as following:

Different staff have access to different document folders through dfId based on sType. The documentfolder contains different documents based on their Id and type.

I am trying to test if a document is listed last in the documentfolder table. I want to do this by testing the title against each other to keep the documentfolder alphabetically ordered, with the last document of the stack being the last alphabetically. 
This is what I got:

```
SELECT d.title
FROM document d1, document d2, documentfolder df, staff s
WHERE s.sType = 'manager'
AND s.dfId = df.dfId
AND df.type = 'financial'
AND df.dId = d1.dId
AND df.dId = d2.dId
AND d1.title > d2.title
```

As a result I get 0 hits while running the test with data that should collide.
Any thoughts?

Comment: SQL relations have no ordering. It does not matter the order in which the rows were inserted.

Comment: Perhaps: AND d1.title >= d2.title

Comment: Please do not use the archaic notation for joining tables; there's been no need to do so for a couple of decades now.  Use the explicit JOIN notation.  As already noted, there is no 'last element' in a table, so there is no 'last element'.  Your query is malformed; the `SELECT d.title` is using an undefined alias `d` instead of either `d1` or `d2`.  You would be more convincing if you showed sample data (one staff record, one documentfolder record and at least two document records).

Comment: I have read this a couple of times and all it got me is a vague idea. Do you want a single row as result? Please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood your question, but this will return a flag for each title whether it is the last document or not. You can add more columns to the result if you need more.

```
select title, 
       rn = 1 as is_last_document
from (
  SELECT d.*,
         row_number() over (order by title desc) as rn
  FROM document, 
    JOIN documentfolder df ON df.dId = d.dId
    JOIN staff s ON s.dfId = df.dfId
  WHERE s.sType = 'manager'
    AND df.type = 'financial'
) t
order by title;
```